# How can I use ternary in filter function?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to filter in the function. I tried, but it is not working correctly.

My task is if **target_variable** is true then only that true object will return, not all objects.

You can see activeColumns for example: not all **target_variable** are true, but right now all the object are getting displayed. Those **target_variable** value are false or if all target value is false then I have a second condition (that else case), but right now second case getting executed means this case **: data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT'** getting executed.

```js
  activeColumns: [
    {
      "column_name": "pk",
      "data_type": "BIGINT",
      "type": "continous",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": false,
      "final_format": "int"
    },
    {
      "column_name": "dewp",
      "data_type": "float",
      "type": "continous",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": true,
      "final_format": ""
    },
    {
      "column_name": "hmdy",
      "data_type": "float",
      "type": "continous",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": false,
      "final_format": ""
    },
    {
      "column_name": "mdct",
      "data_type": "TEXT",
      "type": "string",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": false,
      "user_format": "",
      "final_format": ""
    },
    {
      "column_name": "wdct",
      "data_type": "float",
      "type": "continous",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": false,
      "final_format": ""
    }
  ]
<Autocomplete
        options={
          activeColumns
            ? activeColumns
                .filter((data) =>
                  data.target_variable === true
                    ? data.target_variable === true
                    : data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT'
                )
            : []
        }
/>
```

Comment: 1) Please don't [delete your question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76218188/how-can-i-use-ternary-in-filter-function) and then ask basically exactly the same question (again with the run-on paragraphs) and expect a different outcome. 2) You should really heed Jared's advice from that deleted question and not have nested ternary statements _at all_.

Comment: This produces the results I would expect: https://jsfiddle.net/n4j9evp8/  In what way do these results differ from what you expect and why?  Please update the question to a runnable [mcve] which demonstrates the result and indicate what isn't working as expected.

Comment: @Andy got it but I think in that question many of them get confused

Comment: @devdeveloper your code is working as expected, what's your expected output ?

Comment: @David in your example you consoled the result if you can see in the console all are getting displayed but if you see the second object of the array target_variable is true in that case only I want that second object if all objects target_variable are false then I need to check else

Comment: @devdeveloper: *"you can see in the console all are getting displayed"* - No, I can see in the console that only the filtered results (which match the condition used when filtering) are being displayed.  Even simply counting the results demonstrates that there are fewer objects in the filtered array.  Please update your question to a runnable [mcve] (just like the JSFiddle link I created) which demonstrates the code being used and please indicate specifically how that result isn't what you expected.

Comment: @David it is filtering using data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT'  this else case

Comment: in all objects one object target_variable is true I need that to get in the console if true this is first case

Comment: @devdeveloper: It is filtering out any objects which don't match the condition provided in the `filter` function.  Because that's what the `filter` function does.  The ternary operator isn't even needed here, the logic is identical to this: `data.target_variable === true || (data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT')`  You're seeing all records which match that condition.  Exactly as defined in the code.

Comment: i already tried this condition data.target_variable === true || (data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT') but this also print all that target_variable have false value

Comment: @devdeveloper: *"but will print all that target_variable have false value"* - Once again, this is **demonstrably untrue** by the example provided.  For example, the column name "mdct" has a `target_variable` of `false` and is not printed in the results.  You are encouraged to stop assuming and start actually testing and debugging your code.  We can't help you fix code that isn't broken.

Comment: if data.target_variable === true then only     {
      "column_name": "dewp",
      "data_type": "float",
      "type": "continous",
      "target_timeseries": false,
      "target_variable": true,
      "final_format": ""
    } this one need to get in console

Comment: for case why is not print "mdct" because I am checking data_type in the second case in ternary

Comment: @devdeveloper: *"only this one need to get in console"* - You're misunderstanding how boolean logic works.  When the filter logic is "X || Y" then it will match records which meet the criteria of X ***or*** Y.  If you want it to be X ***and*** Y then you would use `&&` instead: `data.target_variable === true && (data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT')`

Comment: then if all target_variable get false  based on you and condition nothing will return

Comment: if all  target_variable are false then i will check this data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT' case

Comment: @devdeveloper: *"nothing will return"* - If you would [bother to test it before making demonstrably false assumptions and claims](https://jsfiddle.net/7oagrwx0/) then you would observe otherwise.  At this point you're clearly just trolling the community and not actually trying to solve a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You need to apply two filters, first on `target_variable===true`, and (only) if that gives no result, then apply the second filter. Ternary is not usable inside the filter condition in such a case.

**Demo:**

```js
const activeColumns = [
  { "column_name": "pk", "data_type": "BIGINT", "type": "continous", "target_timeseries": false, "target_variable": false, "final_format": "int" },
  { "column_name": "dewp", "data_type": "float", "type": "continous", "target_timeseries": false, "target_variable": true, "final_format": "" },
  { "column_name": "hmdy", "data_type": "float", "type": "continous", "target_timeseries": false, "target_variable": false, "final_format": "" },
  { "column_name": "mdct", "data_type": "TEXT", "type": "string", "target_timeseries": false, "target_variable": false, "user_format": "", "final_format": "" },
  { "column_name": "wdct", "data_type": "float", "type": "continous", "target_timeseries": false, "target_variable": false, "final_format": "" }
];

const applyFilter = (activeColumns) => {
  let result = activeColumns.filter(data => data.target_variable);
  if (result.length === 0)
    result = activeColumns.filter(data => data.column_name !== 'pk' && data.data_type !== 'TEXT');
  return result;
}

console.log("One item has target_variable===true")
console.log(applyFilter(activeColumns));

activeColumns[1].target_variable = false;
console.log("All items have target_variable===false")
console.log(applyFilter(activeColumns));
```